# How to go from Apache Kafka to Confluent Platform?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a dockerized `Apache Kafka` cluster (each `vm` runs one `docker` container which in turn runs one instance of both `kafka` and `zookeeper`) set up and with topics and messages in it already. Using mostly `logstash` as producers, `logstash` and `node-kafka` as consumers. How do I convert the system to use the newly released [Confluent Platform](http://www.confluent.io/) with no downtime?

The `REST API` would save me a lot of time but it seems to me that the `REST API` requires the `Schema Registry` to be running. First of all, how did I survive without a `Schema Registry` before and second, why do I need it now? What would happen to the data that's already in `Apache Kafka`?

Since everything has to be containerized, what are the recommendations? multiple `Dockerfile`s or one single `Dockerfile` for everything? Currently I have only one `Dockerfile` and use `supervisord` to start both `kafka` and `zookeeper`.

Comment: Did you find a headway with these issues?

Comment: hmmm it was never implemented when i was there. the whole idea of a schema registry was too costly for the system we had because the fields in logs was not really standardized. I'm sure it'd be really useful if you are building sth from scratch, tho. Just a side note, i use aws kinesis or sns+sqs these days and i'm happy with how simple they are to work with

Answer (score 2):

Confluent released (experimental) Docker images at https://github.com/confluentinc/docker-images